# Execute multiple calls of an async function sequentially

Tags: swift, asynchronous

Let's say I have an async function:

```
func doAsyncWork() async throws { ... }
```

The function can be called from multiple places. What I want to achieve is to ensure that the function is never executed multiple times simultaneously. For example, if someone calls that function while it is still being executed by the first caller, it should queue the second call until the first call finishes (and so on, with proper errors propagation). The order of calls must be preserved, so something like a FIFO queue for calls that have not yet been processed will likely be needed.

I'd like to avoid using external libraries/frameworks like RxSwift just for this purpose, so I'm looking for a vanilla Swift solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Put it in an `actor`.

Comment: Since the work is asynchronous, making it a member function of an actor would not solve it, since actors are reentrant. This would end up having overlapping operations. I could vision an actor with a function `enqueue(operation: @escaping () async -> T) async -> T` (and friends) which internally uses either Combine or AsyncSequences as the FIFO and managing a tuple of the operation and the task continuation as queue value. There's probably a simpler solution, when the problem is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is my non-AI "Q&D" solution. ;)

**Edit**

This version fixed the issues (see explanation below).

It can be certainly improved regarding more versatility regarding the operations, i.e. input parameters and throwing.

```
func makePublisher<Output>(
    operation: @escaping () async -> Output
) -> some Publisher<Output, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        Task {
            let output = await operation()
            promise(.success(output))
        }
    }
}


actor TaskQueue<Value> {
    
    private struct Effect {
        private let f: () -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never>
        let continuation: CheckedContinuation<Value, Never>
        
        init(
            operation: @escaping () async -> Value,
            continuation: CheckedContinuation<Value, Never>
        ) {
            self.f = { makePublisher(operation: operation).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            self.continuation = continuation
        }
        
        func invoke() -> AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
            f()
        }
    }
    
    typealias Operation = () async -> Value
    typealias Continuation = CheckedContinuation<Value, Never>
    
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable!
    private var input = PassthroughSubject<Effect, Never>()
        
    init(maxTasks: Int = 1, bufferSize: Int = 100) {
        self.cancellable = input
        .buffer(size: bufferSize, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .customError({ fatalError("queue full") }))
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(maxTasks)) { effect in
            effect.invoke().map { [continuation = effect.continuation] in ($0, continuation) }
        }
        .sink { value, continuation in
            continuation.resume(returning: value)
        }
    }
    
    func enqueue(_ operation: @escaping Operation) async -> Value {
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            self.send(operation: operation, continuation: continuation)
        }
    }
    
    private func send(operation: @escaping Operation, continuation: Continuation) {
        self.input.send(
            Effect(
                operation: operation,
                continuation: continuation
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
    func testTaskQueue() async throws {
        let taskQueue = TaskQueue<Void>()
                
        // Call the function from multiple places

        try await withThrowingDiscardingTaskGroup { group in
            group.addTask {
                print(Date(), "enqueue")
                await taskQueue.enqueue {
                    print(Date(), "0 executing")
                    try! await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(1000))
                    print(Date(), "0 finished")
                }
                print(Date(), "0 done")
            }
            group.addTask {
                print(Date(), "enqueue")
                await taskQueue.enqueue {
                    print(Date(), "1 executing")
                    try! await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(1000))
                    print(Date(), "1 finished")
                }
                print(Date(), "1 done")
            }
            group.addTask {
                print(Date(), "enqueue")
                await taskQueue.enqueue {
                    print(Date(), "2 executing")
                    try! await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(1000))
                    print(Date(), "2 finished")
                }
                print(Date(), "2 done")
            }
            group.addTask {
                print(Date(), "enqueue")
                await taskQueue.enqueue {
                    print(Date(), "3 executing")
                    try! await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(1000))
                    print(Date(), "3 finished")
                }
                print(Date(), "3 done")
            }
        }
        
        print("done")
    }
```

**Output**

```
2024-03-08 13:06:23 +0000 enqueue
2024-03-08 13:06:23 +0000 enqueue
2024-03-08 13:06:23 +0000 enqueue
2024-03-08 13:06:23 +0000 enqueue
2024-03-08 13:06:23 +0000 0 executing
2024-03-08 13:06:24 +0000 0 finished
2024-03-08 13:06:24 +0000 0 done
2024-03-08 13:06:24 +0000 1 executing
2024-03-08 13:06:26 +0000 1 finished
2024-03-08 13:06:26 +0000 1 done
2024-03-08 13:06:26 +0000 2 executing
2024-03-08 13:06:27 +0000 2 finished
2024-03-08 13:06:27 +0000 2 done
2024-03-08 13:06:27 +0000 3 executing
2024-03-08 13:06:28 +0000 3 finished
2024-03-08 13:06:28 +0000 3 done
done
```

**Explanation of the bug before the update**

Due to the `flatMap` being limited by "max operation", we need to provide a buffer to hold the incoming operations. The PassthroughSubject *would not do it* for us and when a new operation will be enqueued, the pending one will be simply "overridden" and deleted before the operation has been executed. This caused the error "SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE".

Comment: Thank you, I tested it
`let queue = TaskQueue<String>(); Task { await queue.enqueue(doAsyncWork) }; Task { await queue.enqueue(doAsyncWork) }; `
but only the first call was completed and it ended up with an error `SWIFT TASK CONTINUATION MISUSE: enqueue(_:) leaked its continuation!`

Comment: @DominikPalo Yes, unfortunately, the Q&D solution does not work. So it needs more thought.

Comment: @DominikPalo Fixed the issue. The solution is a bit more elaborated.